# Sniffing Android Application HTTPS Traffic

Tags: android, ssl, apk

I have an application on an Android phone (emulator) which sends a `https` request. How I can see that request?

Comment: If it is possible to see the Request structure then We can easily hack many applications including Facebook, Gmail by snatching username/password. What you think?

Answer (score 6):

That is easily possible with a software such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). They have an inbuild SSL server that will position itself in between the app and the server. It is kind of a "Man-in-the-Middle" attack, just that you are only attacking yourself.

After installing the software on your PC you will have to set the IP address of this PC as proxy server in Android. And secondly you will have to install the Root Certificate that the software is using on your Android device.

As you are not breaking any encryption and not reverse engineering any application here, I don't think this will classify as illegal. And as you need to have physical access to the device, you also cannot spy on anyone else than yourself.

Comment: This does not work anymore. App (that we want to intercept traffic) needs to be configure to trust user added certificates (own CA cert in this case). User added certificates are no longer trusted on application level. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Comment: You can install a system certificate by copying it to /system/etc/security/cacerts if you have a rooted phone

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating with your own server, and you have access to its private key, you can use Wireshark to capture packets and have it decrypt the HTTPS traffic. If you are trying to reverse engineer someone else's app, this may or may not be legal and generally cannot be done.